# Is this laptop configuration compatible for blender

Tags: compatibility

I'm thinking of buying a new laptop. It's an iBall CompBook Excelance (more details can be viewed [here](http://www.iball.co.in/Product/Excelance/11187)). Is it compatible to use blender smoothly without any errors or issues in the given configuration in that website. Any suggestions

Comment: Have you compared the specifications of the laptop you intend to purchase with those on [this page](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)?

Comment: @brasshat thats the reason im confused shall i purchase to make small model not detail models, will it be compatible

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is, if you are like me, it won't be long before the "small models" you think now that you're going to make become larger and more complex. I'd always suggest skipping the lowest alternative and purchasing a more robust device for that reason.

Comment: Nearly any computer you can buy today will run Blender, but perhaps just for simple tasks or very slowly...  and I agree with others here.

Comment: @atek hardware recomendations are not well suited for the format of this site and are considered off topic. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/418/add-no-hardware-questions-to-help-center  you might want to post in https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?44-Technical-Support or http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: hardware recommendations are off topic, but I took a quick peek at the specs, and that is a very cheap and flashy laptop. Anything with an Intel Atom processor is not going to run blender very quickly. Plus it has no GPU, so many of blender features may not even work. The 2gb of memory is *barely* enough to use windows, let alone a computationally heavy program like blender. So no I would **not** recommend that laptop. (this is a **very** low end laptop, we are talking about a $150 machine)

Answer (score 1):

With an Intel Atom processor (which is not very good for graphics) and only 2gb of RAM it won't be your best choice, though I did start using Blender with an Intel i3 and 4gb of RAM which was just OK.

My suggestions: I don't recommend using an AMD processor as I've heard the compatibility with Blender is not very good (and they're not very strong overall). I would recommend a laptop with either an Intel i3 or i5 processor, which have integrated graphics (not as good as a graphics card but better than nothing) which does make them cost a bit more but rendering and the really everything will be much faster within Blender. For cheaper processors I would look at the Intel Xeon series. If you are looking for cheaper laptop, don't get any in-built graphics card though they are very good to have (NVIDIA is your better selection in contrast to AMD and 4gb should be enough). RAM isn't as important but if you do a lot of simulations, video editing or animation (or any other tasks that require caching) RAM is somewhat important, I recommend a minimum of 4gb.

Conclusion: I would look at the $US500 price range to get a low to low-mid range laptop. 
This is a list of parts that i woul recommend

- Intel i5 Processor
- 8gb of RAM
- 128 SSD (this is not necessary but will speed up tasks)

These would give you a quite good mid range laptop but at the same time being somewhat cheap ($US450 - $US800) laptop also suitable for gaming and photo editing.

Things to look out for:

- Don't get an AMD processor
- Make sure your processor has a minimum of 2GHz
- NVIDIA makes better compatible graphics card for Blender that AMD
- Useless hardware like only 8gb of SSD memory or a full HD monitor screen that is smaller than 15"

This [link](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) is the official requirements for blender and suggestions.

Comment: thanks for giving a brief information i would think for it. As i do not create much complex model.